# Return data from database with concat

Tags: javascript, php

I have a textbox with the `ID` and `NAME` called "name". In my database I have firstname, preposition, lastname. In SQL I am using concat to combine these to a "name".

When I am trying to echo the result `$result['name']` I get a browser error.

I guess something is wrong with the multiple variable `$name =` in my code. But I could not fix it.

Does someone know what is wrong with my code?

```
<?php    
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
}else {
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    $name = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
    $name .= isset($_POST['preposition']) ? $_POST['preposition'] : '';
    $name .= isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';

    $query = 'SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', preposition, ' ', lastname) as name FROM users WHERE id="' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $id) . '"';    
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo $result['name'];   
  }else{
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo $result['name']; 
  }    
} 

?>
```

**Edit 1:**

Textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    function getUser(value) { // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price 
    console.log("getUser before ajax", jQuery('#id').val());
    jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: './get/get5.php', 
    method: 'POST', 
    data: {'id' : jQuery('#id').val()},
    success: function(response){ 
        console.log("getUser after ajax", jQuery('#id').val());
        jQuery('#name').val(response);
    }, 
    error: function (request, status, error) { 
        alert(request.responseText); 
    }, 
    });                 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I cant see the error. There opens an empty message and there is no data posted into the textbox. When I try to post only the firstname, without concat and multiple variables $name the script works

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, even escaping is not 100% safe, you need to use prepared statements.

Comment: would you please echo $query and print_r() the result and tell us what you  find there

Comment: Where are you using `$name`?

Comment: what is id ??? in else part, it must be $id as this is a variable

Comment: In my original code it is $id. I mistyped in my question

Comment: ok echo your $query and show what find

Comment: See edit 1 in my first post. I am using name in the textbox and javascript

Comment: The return of the query is right

Comment: There must be something wrong with: `$name = ` and `$name .= `

Comment: still not fixed